# How to render points using InkManager

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am using InkManager to render things on the screen and able to capture x y position.

**Technology:** WinRT/Windows Store App using C#

**What I am trying to do:**
I want to pass x, y position to InkManager for rendering things.

**What I am not getting is:**
I can't find constructor for PointerPoint (which are needed to pass as parameter in ProcessPointerDown, ProcessPointerUp and ProcessPointerUpdate).

Data structure doesn't matter to me. It can be PointerPoint or any thing else.

I can't find any way to pass my data to InkManager for rendering.

**Sample Application:** https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/tag/inkmanager/

Is there any way I can give points as input data to InkManager for rendering?

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new InkStrokes from points with an [InkStrokeBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.input.inking.inkstrokebuilder.aspx).

You cannot directly generate PointerPoints to pass to the InkManager, but you can take the points, generate a new InkStroke, and then call InkManager.[AddStroke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh920324.aspx).